# Can we grab all youtube videos from drupal7 node contents?

Tags: drupal

Can anyone give me hint how can I grab all youtube videos from drupal7 node contents? 
Actually I want to grab all youtube videos from node contents then that link I want to save in spreadsheet.

Comment: What's a drupal7 node content? What have you tried? Are you writing client side code? Server side code?

Comment: We have youtube videos in node body posted through iframe, can we grab that all videos link to spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view (and select your specific content type that has the Youtube videos embedded into it).  If you are not using views module already, install [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module first so that you can create a view.

After that use either [Views Excel Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) module OR [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to export the node bodies to excel sheets.

**Note:** This approach will give you entire content of the node bodies (not just the iframe code of the video) into the excel sheets. However, you can easily find the iframe codes within those excel sheets with simple **ctrl+f**.